# RegEx matching standalone string with dashes

Tags: regex, string

I need to write a RegEx to match the "1-234-5678" string if there are no dash characters around it.

I have the following RegEx:

```
\b\d\-\d{3}\-\d{4}\b
```

Now this works fine and matches "1-234-5678" correctly in the strings below:

- text 1-234-5678 text
- 111 1-234-5678 1212

The RegEx also correctly NOT matches "1-234-5678" in the strings below:

- text1-234-5678text
- 1111-234-56781212

But the problem is that it also matches in the following strings:

- text-1-234-5678-text
- 111-1-234-5678-1212

It's because `\b` matches before and after the dashes.

How can I eliminate matches if there's a dash in front or after the data?

Comment: Replace `\b` with `\s`?

Comment: It implies that there should be a space in front and after it, and the space will be part of the match. Not a good solution.

Comment: ?:\s\d\-\d{3}\-\d{4} is an invalid RegEx. Not a good solution.

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: I test in ultraedit using Perl compatible RegEx. When I switch over to Unix RegExes then it's a valid regex, but still no correct match.

Comment: What language will you be using this in?

Comment: (?<=\s)<ur regex>(?=\s|$)

Comment: .NET in visual studio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a negative lookbehind and negative lookahead to check whether the above mentioned format is not preceded and followed by a `-` symbol,

```
(?<!-)\b\d\-\d{3}\-\d{4}\b(?!-)
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/lK9iD2/4)

Comment: This is it. Perfect, tanks.